# OpenMP - index variable in OpenMP 'for' statement must have signed integral type

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, openmp, multicore

I'm new to OpenMP. I'm trying to use multiple cores for a for loop but I get this compiling error:

"error C3016: 'x' : index variable in OpenMP 'for' statement must have signed integral type".

I know OpenMP 2.0, which is standard with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ( what I'm using ), does not support unsigned data types for some reason but I don't believe I have any unsigned data types being used in this loop.

Here is how my code looks like:

Variable Declerations:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float x, y;
};

FractalGenerator::Vertex FractalGenerator::_fracStart;
FractalGenerator::Vertex FractalGenerator::_fracEnd;
float FractalGenerator::_pointPrecision = 0.008f;
float FractalGenerator::_scaleFactor = 1;
```

For Loop:

```
float _fracStep =  _pointPrecision / _scaleFactor;

#pragma omp parallel for
for (float x = _fracStart.x; x < _fracEnd.x; x += _fracStep)
{
    for (float y = _fracStart.y; y < _fracEnd.y; y += _fracStep)
    {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like OpenMP doesn't support non-integral types as the index in a `for` loop. You have `float x`, and while `float` is an arithmetic type, it's not an integral type.

An integral type is one of: `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, and any of the signed and unsigned integer types (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long`).

You'll need to convert your algorithm to use one of these for the index of your `for` loop. This might work:

```
int iEnd = (_fracEnd.x - _fracStart.x) / _fracStep;
int jEnd = (_fracEnd.y - _fracStart.y) / _fracStep;
for (int i = 0; i < iEnd; i++)
{
  float x = _fracStart.x + i * _fracStep;
  for (int j = 0; j < jEnd; j++)
  {
    float y = _fracStart.y + j * _fracStep;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you were right. Wow that's a bummer. Looks like I'll have to find a different parallel programming API. Thanks!

Comment: One way may well be to just mulitply up your floating point values so that you can use integers, and then divide inside the loop. Floating point divide isn't that terrible in performans, so if you have enough processors, it should still give you a nice boost.

Comment: @cstuts, you can use OpenMP, just iterate `currentStep` variable, instead of `x` where `x =  _fracStart.x + currentStep * _fracStep`

Comment: @Lol4t0 I was just adding that to my answer!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what currentStep would be. Could you maybe demonstrate an example from the code snippet I provided?

Comment: It worked but I had to modify it a bit. int iEnd = (_fracEnd.x - _fracStart.x) / _fracStep; int jEnd = (_fracEnd.y - _fracStart.y) / _fracStep;

Comment: In recent OpenMP standards integer, pointer and iterator types are allowed for canonical for loop: http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf#page=63 "2.6 Canonical Loop Form" - "`var` One of the following:
A variable of a signed or unsigned integer type. For C++, a variable of a random access iterator type. For C, a variable of a pointer type."